# How to create Angular 2 multi select drop-down list with grouping?

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular2-directives, multi-select

Hi I am working on AngularJS 2. I am newbie to AngularJS 2. I am trying to create multi select drop-down list with checkbox's. I have downloaded  npm install angular2-multiselect-dropdown. Multi select drop-down list is working fine. Below is my html template.

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownListScopes" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemsScopes"
                                                  [settings]="dropdownSettingsScopes"
                                                  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                                                  (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
                                                  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                                                  (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to edit this drop-down list such way that all options should have main menu. I want to implement grouping feature. In documentation i do not see any methods to group by. Can someone help me to implement this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/grouping/
that should help

```html
import { GroupResult, groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <kendo-multiselect
            [data]="groupedData"
            [textField]="'name'"
            [valueField]="'name'">
        </kendo-multiselect>
    </div>
  `
})
class AppComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = [
        { name: "Pork", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" },
        { name: "Pepper", category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" },
        { name: "Beef", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" }
    ];
    public groupedData: GroupResult[] = groupBy(this.data, [{field: "subcategory"}]);
}
```